# Energy conservation for the wave equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, mathematical-physics, wave-equation

I recently encountered this problem in PDE class involving a concept I have never met, it states:

> $ u_{tt} - u_{xx} = 0 ; \space \space 0 < x < 1 ; \space \space t > 0 $
>
> $ u(0,t)=u(1,t)=0 $
>
> $ u(x,0) = x(1-x) $
>
> $ u_t (x,0) = 0 $
>
> We are to use the law of energy conservation for this problem to determine the sum:
>
> $$ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2k-1)^4} $$

All I can do here is separate variables to solve the problem via eigenfunctions expansions but I do not believe I have encountered the term Energy Conservation for the wave equation and how it can be used to find this sort of sum, I know about Green's functions and how they can be used to find the sums of inverse eigenvalues, so I need someone to help me with this in telling me what this term means and possibly direct me to a source or demonstration of this sort of solution. All help appreciated thanks

Comment: Although it isn't really relevant to the problem, you should be aware that the equation in your problem is not the heat equation but the wave equation.

Comment: @AndreasBlass : Please forgive me I have corrected this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We solve this by computing the Fourier series of $u = x(1-x)$ and then evaluating $\int_0^1 u_x^2 {\rm d}x$ (the energy) in two different ways.

The Fourier series of $u(x,0) = x(1-x)$ on $[0,1]$ is
$$u(x,0) = \frac{8}{\pi^3}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin[\pi (2n-1) x]}{(2n-1)^3}$$

The energy of the system is given as $H = \frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 u_x^2 + u_t^2{\rm d}x$ as derived in the other answer. At $t=0$ we have $u_t = 0$ so the second term does not contribute.

First by using $u(x,0)=x(1-x)$ we find
$$H = \frac{1}{2}\int_0^1(1-2x)^2{\rm d}x = \frac{1}{6}$$

and secondly by using the Fourier series representation of the solution we also have

$$\begin{align}H &= \frac{32}{\pi^4}\int_0^1 \sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{\cos[\pi (2n-1) x]\cos[\pi (2m-1) x]}{(2n-1)^2(2m-1)^2} {\rm d}x \\&= \frac{16}{\pi^4}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n-1)^4}\end{align}$$

Equating the two results gives us

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n-1)^4} = \frac{\pi^4}{96}$$

As you can see this problem has little to do with the acctual PDE and energy conservation per se, and is more just an exercise in working with Fourier series.

Answer (score 2):

For the first part note that 
$$
\frac{d}{dt}(u_t^2/2)=u_tu_{tt}=u_tu_{xx},
$$
then after an integration by parts and up to boundary terms, you will find the Hamiltonian
$$
H=\frac {1}{2}\int_0^1(u_t^2+u_x^2)dx
$$ 
or the energy, a conserved quantity. For the value of the sum I think you have to expand with respect to a suitable base of [0,1].